# How do i make my burger menu into 9 dots?

Tags: html, css

Im currently making the google homepage and I need to make a bento menu with other words a 9 doted menu.

The way I tried to make it was by first making a burger menu and adding **text-decoration: dotted;** I thought this would make the strings in my menu dotted but it didnt.

```css
.bento-string {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bento-menu">
  <div class="bento-string"></div>
  <div class="bento-string"></div>
  <div class="bento-string"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @John Englund welcome to SO ! Please check my answer and let me know if that helped you !

Comment: @PascalLamers thank you for the help but unfortunately it didnt work. It seems like turning a burger menu into a bento menu isnt the right way to do it:(

Comment: I am afraid I haven't heard the term "bento menu" , therefore I must have misinterpreted your question. I thought you were trying to "underline" your strings with a dotted line. Can you try again to explain how the menu should look like ?

Comment: @PascalLamers my bad! Im trying to achieve this: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2HgJ.png].

Comment: Gotch ! I updated my answer, take a look

Comment: @PascalLamers Thank you so much it solved my problem! The reason why i wanted to make the menu into code was because i wanted to add a hover effect so it turns a little bit lighter. I do not think that works in the same way if im using a svg if it does it would be very useful to know:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve something looking like a "bento-menu" icon you can try css grid for example. Take a look at the following.

```css
.bento-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 2px;
  grid-row-gap: 2px;
  height : 22px;
  width : 22px;
}

.bento-dot {
  width : 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background:#000000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bento-menu">
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
  <div class="bento-dot"></div>
</div>
```

But I would strongly suggest using a common svg icon, if it is just used as icon. Depends on what are you trying to do with it.

Comment: Got a tiny typo in CSS of `.bento-dot`: 'with' instead of 'width'

Comment: Thanks ! I changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** added 'full menu' code with all buttons from the image plus new 'bearclaw' (OP missed that one...)

**UPDATE2** added SVG version of the fullmenu icons for code and approach comparison. You could simply create an SVG document with al kinds if required icons and use them in your main document.

However, I chose to define

- 4 base shapes => symbols: `dot, sqr, lnh, lnv`
- 2 combined shapes using base shapes => symbols: `s-row, s-col`
- menu icons with above 6 shapes => symbols `hamburger, bearclaw, donner, bento, meatballs, kebab` and extra `d-row3`.

...just because I could.

**introduction**

Some time ago I created a generic responsive *2D patch grid mechanism* with 'Flexbox Layout' (inspired on the Android 9-patch graphic), which may be of interest to you as an alternative to the accepted answer:

```
/*
patch: flexbox container element [mandatory] holding a number of patches (div,ul,ol,etc)
cell : any HTML element, which will become a flexbox container too (div,li,etc)
cell content: anything you like

cells are equally sized and will size to the ratio set by parent sizes on browser resize
*/

/* patch grid CSS */
[patch], [patch]>* { ... }         /* predefined patch grid mechanism */

/* your CSS */
.patch { width: any; height: any } /* main container, mandatory (fixed or relative units) */
.cell  { nothing specific }        /* mechanism takes care of sizes (can do without this) */

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="patch" patch="2x2"> <!-- 2 x 2 = 4 cells -->
    <div class="cell"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="cell"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

The code snippet below is rather large, but heavily commented and shows:

- a few demos showing (a) button(s) like you requested
- what else you can do with the *2D patch grid mechanism* with a few demos
- a simple landing page banding mechanism with responsive page spacing
- simple dot shaping by using 'CSS custom attributes'
- how to use math to create a responsive page (or HTML elements) [reference: MathIsFun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html)
- some preferred CSS global settings

I may have gone a bit overboard with this, but I promise, it is a lot f fun!

```css
/*
    ALL math (y=mx+b) reference: https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html
*/
/**************************/
/* preferred global rules */
/**************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }

/* remove default markup */
body,p { margin: 0 }
ul     { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
ul,li  { list-style-type: none }

/***********************************/
/* easy RESPONSIVE|PATCH GRID|NESS */
/***********************************/

/* for SO62815794 */

/* base flexbox patch grid structure */
[patch],[patch]>* { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap } /* path and cell containers */
[patch]           { align-content: flex-start; position: relative }
[patch]>*         { flex-grow: 1; justify-content: center; align-items: center; overflow: hidden }

/* the "nine-patch", inspired by Android 9-patch image; essentially a 3x3 matrix */
[patch^= "3x"]>*  { height: 33.33333%; max-height: 33.33333% }
[patch*= "x3"]>*  { flex-basis: 33.33333%; max-width : 33.33333% }

/* DEMO extras */

/* add your own specific patch cell sizes like below */
[patch^= "1x"]>*  { height:100%; max-height:100% } [patch*= "x1"]>* { flex-basis: 100%; max-width:100% }
[patch^= "2x"]>*  { height: 50%; max-height: 50% } [patch*= "x2"]>* { flex-basis:  50%; max-width: 50% }
[patch^= "4x"]>*  { height: 25%; max-height: 25% } [patch*= "x4"]>* { flex-basis:  25%; max-width: 25% }
/* 
   7x1 days in a week, 18x8 Periodic Table, 24x1 hours in a day, 22x6 keyboard+numpad, etc.
   just divide 100% by the required XxY values
*/

/* when less elements than required by patch */
[patch][fill=""]>:last-child,[patch][fill*="H"]>:last-child { max-width : 100% }
[patch][fill=""]>:last-child,[patch][fill*="V"]>:last-child { max-height: 100% }

/*********************************/
/* FULL MENU DEMO for SO62815794 */
/*********************************/

/* 'full menu' demo band settings */
[band*="fullmenu"]>* { margin: 0.5rem 1.5rem }
[band]>[band]        { align-self: flex-start }

/*
    Instead of assigning sizes to specific classes,
    define size attributes all elements can use.

    precursor/alternative to using 'CSS Variables'
*/
/*
  sizes for full square buttons (hamburger,bearclaw,dönner,bento) 
  and 1/3rd square buttons (kebab,meatballs)
*/
[size*="w1"] { width : calc(5vmin + 16px) }          /* (320,32)(1920,112) */
[size*="h1"] { height: calc(5vmin + 16px) }
[size*="w3"] { width : calc(1.6667vmin + 5.3333px) } /* 1/3rd */
[size*="h3"] { height: calc(1.6667vmin + 5.3333px) }

/* either/or shape attributes, button contents is either lines, squares or dots  */
[shape]>*>*         { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); cursor: pointer }
[shape*="lnh"]>*>*  { width : 100%; height:  70% } /* horizontal lines */
[shape*="lnv"]>*>*  { width :  70%; height: 100% } /* vertical lines */
[shape*="sq" ]>*>*  { width :  75%; height:  75% } /* squares */
[shape*="dt" ]>*>*  { width :  80%; height:  80%; border-radius: 50% } /* dots */

/* Specific to 'dönner' button, has tapered content */
[shape*=".tpw"]>*             { margin: 0 auto } /* to center the lines */
[shape*=".tpw"]>:nth-child(1) { max-width : 100%; height: 70% } /* taper width 1 */
[shape*=".tpw"]>:nth-child(2) { max-width :  70%; height: 70% } /* taper width 2 */
[shape*=".tpw"]>:nth-child(3) { max-width :  40%; height: 70% } /* taper width 3 */

/* eye-candy animation, redundant */
[shape]:hover                { transform: scale(1.03) }
[shape]:active               { transform: scale(1) }
[shape]:hover>*>:not(:hover) { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6) }
[shape]>*>:hover             { background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.9) }

/************************/
/* DEMOS for SO62815794 */
/************************/
/* demo 1, patch grid buttons */
.patch-1,.patch-3 { /* square using y=mx+b */
    width : calc(5vmin + 16px); /* (320,32)(1920,112) */
    height: calc(5vmin + 16px);
} /* square */

.patch-2 { /* half a square using y=mx+b  */
    width : calc(5vmin + 16px); /* (320,32)(1920,112) */
    height: calc(2.5vmin + 8px); /* (320,16)(1920,56) */
} /* half a square */

[class^="patch-"]>*>*,   /* anything cell content */
[class^="patch-"] .dot { /* or .dot */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width : 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
/* demo 2, patch grid */
/* main container, mandatory (fixed or relative units) */
.patch {
    width : calc(10vmax + 32px); /* (320,64)(1920,224) */
    height: calc(10vmax + 32px)
}
/* mechanism takes care of sizes, just eye-candy */
.cell  { outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4) }

/* SUDOKU, demo patch grid use */
.sudoku {
    /* responsive width and height using y = mx + b */
    height: calc(11.25vw + 264px); /* (320,300)(1920,480) */
    width : calc(11.25vw + 264px); /* (320,300)(1920,480) */
}

/******************/
/* eye-candy only */
/******************/
/* responsive patch font size using y = mx + b */
[patch] { font-size: calc(0.9375vw + 4px); /* (320, 7)(1280,16) */ }

/* class starts with... */
[class^="patch-"]          { margin: 1rem }

[class^="patch-"]:hover    { transform: scale(1.03) }
[class^="patch-"]:active   { transform: scale(1)    }

[class^="patch-"]>*>*      { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6); cursor: pointer }
[class^="patch-"]>*>:hover { background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1) }

[class^="patch-"]:hover>*>:not(:hover) { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) }

.sudoku [patch]            { font-size: calc(0.625vw + 10px); /* (320,12)(1280,18) */ }
.sudoku ul:nth-child(odd)  { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05) }
.sudoku ul:nth-child(even) { background-color: White }
.sudoku,.sudoku li         { outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2) }

.sudoku ul:hover,
.sudoku li:hover { background-color: rgba(47, 79, 79,.3) } /* DarkSlateGrey */

/***********************************************/
/* various border radii for odd shaped buttons */
/***********************************************/
/*                      Position:  T   R   B   L */
[radius^="0000"] { border-radius:  0   0   0   0  } /* full square */
[radius^="0001"] { border-radius:  0   0   0  50% }
[radius^="0010"] { border-radius:  0   0  50%  0  }
[radius^="0011"] { border-radius:  0   0  50% 50% }
[radius^="0100"] { border-radius:  0  50%  0   0  }
[radius^="0101"] { border-radius:  0  50%  0  50% }
[radius^="0110"] { border-radius:  0  50% 50%  0  }
[radius^="0111"] { border-radius:  0  50% 50% 50% }
[radius^="1000"] { border-radius: 50%  0   0   0  }
[radius^="1001"] { border-radius: 50%  0   0  50% }
[radius^="1010"] { border-radius: 50%  0  50%  0  }
[radius^="1011"] { border-radius: 50%  0  50% 50% }
[radius^="1100"] { border-radius: 50% 50%  0   0  }
[radius^="1101"] { border-radius: 50% 50%  0  50% }
[radius^="1110"] { border-radius: 50% 50% 50%  0  }
[radius^="1111"] { border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% } /* full circle */


/* responsive base font size using y = mx + b */
html   { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) } /* (320,14)(1280,20) */
/* change default font-size in browser font settings to see effect */

[band]            { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; }
[band*="rows"]    { flex-direction: column }
[band*="cols"]    { flex-direction: row }

[band],[centered] { justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center }

body[padded="1"],
body[padded="0"] [band*="padded"] {
   margin: 0; /* for use with h1...h6 as band */
    /*
        responsive page padding
        and responsive band padding (same as responsive page padding, but at band level)
        p1(320,32) p2(1920, 72) => 0.025x + 24
        p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 
    
        'Band padding' is only active when 'page padding' is off 
    
        The difference between the 2 methods becomes apparent
        when a a band has a background-color (try <body padded="1"> )...
    */
    padding: calc( 2.5vh + 24px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}
body           { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); padding-bottom: 5rem }
[band^="hero"] { background-color: rgba(47, 79, 79,.5) } /* DarkSlateGrey */

/* to show all elements with outlines (put in <body>) */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed }
```

```html
<body padded="0" outlines="0">

<h2 band="hero.padded">for starters: the full menu</h2>
<div band="fullmenu.cols.padded">
    <div band>
        <h3>hamburger</h3>
        <div patch="3x1" size="w1.h1" shape="lnh">
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div band>
        <h3>bearclaw</h3>
        <div patch="1x3" size="w1.h1" shape="lnv">
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div band>
        <h3>dönner</h3>
        <div patch="3x1" size="w1.h1" shape="lnh.tpw">
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div band>
        <h3>bento</h3>
        <div patch="3x3" size="w1.h1" shape="sq">
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div band>
        <h3>kebab</h3>
        <div patch="3x1" size="w3.h1" shape="dt">
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div band>
        <h3>meatballs</h3>
        <div patch="1x3" size="w1.h3" shape="dt">
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
            <div><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 band="hero.padded">demo 1, patch grid buttons</h2>
<div band="demo2.cols.padded">
    <div class="patch-1" patch="3x3">
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
      <div><span class="dot"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="patch-2" patch="2x4">
      <div><span></span></div>
      <div><span></span></div>
      <div><span></span></div>
      <div><span></span></div>
      <div><span></span></div>
      <div><span></span></div>
      <div><span></span></div>
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="patch-3" patch="2x2">
      <div><span radius="0111"></span></div>
      <div><span radius="1011"></span></div>
      <div><span radius="1110"></span></div>
      <div><span radius="1101"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 band="hero.padded">demo 2, the patch grid</h2>
<div band="demo1.cols.padded">
    <div band>
        <h3>2x2 &lt;div&gt;&lt;p&gt;</h3>
        <div class="patch" patch="2x2">
            <div class="cell"><p>1</p></div>
            <div class="cell"><p>2</p></div>
            <div class="cell"><p>3</p></div>
            <div class="cell"><p>4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div band>
        <h3>fill 2x2 &lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;</h3>
        <ul class="patch" patch="2x2" fill>
            <li class="cell"><p>1</p></li>
            <li class="cell"><p>2</p></li>
            <li class="cell"><p>3</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div band>
        <h3>3x3 &lt;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;</h3>
        <div class="patch" patch="3x3">
            <div class="cell"><div>1</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>2</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>3</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>4</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>5</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>6</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>7</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>8</div></div>
            <div class="cell"><div>9</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 band="hero.padded">sudoku, a patch grid demo</h2>
<div band="demo3.padded">
    <h3>3x3 times 3x3 with &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;</h3>
    <div class="sudoku" patch="3x3">
        <ul patch="3x3"><li> <li>9<li> <li>4<li><li>1<li> <li> <li>3</ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li>2<li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li> </ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li> <li>1<li> <li>3<li><li>9<li>6<li> <li> </ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li> <li> <li>3<li> <li><li> <li>9<li> <li> </ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li>4<li> <li>8<li> <li><li> <li>6<li> <li>1</ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li> <li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li>7</ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li> <li> <li>9<li>6<li><li>7<li> <li>3<li> </ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li> <li> <li> <li> <li><li> <li>7<li> <li>9</ul>
        <ul patch="3x3"><li>1<li> <li> <li>4<li><li>2<li> <li>8<li> </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 band="hero.padded">SVG full menu</h2>
<div band="fullmenu.cols.padded">
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#hamburger"/></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#bearclaw" /></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#donner"   /></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#bento"    /></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#meatballs"/></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#kebab"    /></svg>
</div>

<h2 band="hero.padded">parts for SVG full menu</h2>
<div band="fullmenu.cols.padded">
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#dot"/></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#sqr"/></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#lnh"/></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#lnv"/></svg>

    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#s-row" /></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#s-col"/></svg>
    <svg size="w1.h1"><use href="#d-row3"/></svg>
</div>

<!-- Predefined in-document SVG shapes (and make 'parent' SVG invisible with 0 sizes)  -->
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <style>
        svg:hover  { transform: scale(1.03); fill: rgba(0,0,0,.6) }
        svg:active { transform: scale(1) }

        circle:hover,
        rect:hover { fill: rgba(255,0,0,.9); cursor: pointer }
    </style>

    <symbol id="dot" viewBox="0,0,1,1"  ><circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.45"/></symbol>
    <symbol id="sqr" viewBox="0,0,1,1"  ><rect  x="0" y="0" width="1"   height="1"  /></symbol>
    <symbol id="lnh" viewBox="0,0,1,3.5"><rect  x="0" y="0" width="1"   height="3.5"/></symbol>
    <symbol id="lnv" viewBox="0,0,3.5,1"><rect  x="0" y="0" width="3.5" height="1"  /></symbol>

    <!-- using squares -->

    <symbol id="s-row">
        <use href="#sqr" x="6.25%"  y="0" width="25%"/>
        <use href="#sqr" x="37.5%"  y="0" width="25%"/>
        <use href="#sqr" x="68.75%" y="0" width="25%"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="s-col">
        <use href="#sqr" y="6.25%"  x="0" width="100%" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#sqr" y="37.5%"  x="0" width="100%" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#sqr" y="68.75%" x="0" width="100%" height="25%"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="bento">
        <use href="#s-row" y="6.25%"  x="0" height="25%" />
        <use href="#s-row" y="37.5%"  x="0" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#s-row" y="68.75%" x="0" height="25%"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="hamburger">
        <use href="#lnv" y="6.25%"  x="0" width="100%" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#lnv" y="37.5%"  x="0" width="100%" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#lnv" y="68.75%" x="0" width="100%" height="25%"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="bearclaw">
        <use href="#lnh" x="6.25%"  y="0" height="100%" width="25%"/>
        <use href="#lnh" x="37.5%"  y="0" height="100%" width="25%"/>
        <use href="#lnh" x="68.75%" y="0" height="100%" width="25%"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="donner">
        <use href="#lnv" y="6.25%"  x="0"   width="100%"  height="25%"/>
        <use href="#lnv" y="41%"    x="25%" width="52.5%" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#lnv" y="68.75%" x="35%" width="30%"   height="25%"/>
    </symbol>

    <!-- using dots -->
    <symbol id="meatballs">
        <use href="#dot" x="6.25%"  y="0" width="25%"/>
        <use href="#dot" x="37.5%"  y="0" width="25%"/>
        <use href="#dot" x="68.75%" y="0" width="25%"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="kebab">
        <use href="#dot" y="6.25%"  x="0" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#dot" y="37.5%"  x="0" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#dot" y="68.75%" x="0" height="25%"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="d-row3">
        <use href="#meatballs" y="6.25%"  x="0" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#meatballs" y="37.5%"  x="0" height="25%"/>
        <use href="#meatballs" y="68.75%" x="0" height="25%"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm new to programming so comments like these helps me out alot:) I will check the link and your code tomorrow morning! If you have any advice for someone who is new to programming it would be very much appriciated, especially from someone who has been programming since the 80s:)

Comment: Glad to have been of help! I'm willing to exchange email or something so you can ask away. Cool you checked my profile (I usually do too, pity yours is empty). Need to chat for that, remind me tomorrow (I'm at GMT Amsterdam). Check my other answers as a few recent ones include a thorrow explanation of the math involved.... e.g. [SO62429773](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62429773/2015909)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background and box-shadow. You can also apply transition and modify dot's position

```
  .hamburger:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px);
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #000;
    box-shadow: -12px -12px 0 0 #000, 0px -12px 0 0 #000, 12px -12px 0 0 #000, -12px 0px 0 0 #000, 12px 0px 0 0 #000, -12px 12px 0 0 #000, 0px 12px 0 0 #000, 12px 12px 0 0 #000;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```