# lines with text around the Circle

Tags: css, sass

How to make lines around the circle which holds text for each line. I don't want text to be in the pseudo class. Below is the required output Image

[image].

Below code is which I have tried from Paulie_D previous solutions

```css
.outCircle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.marker {
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.vert {
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.angle-1 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.angle-2 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="outCircle">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="marker horiz"></div>
    <div class="marker vert"></div>
    <div class="marker angle-1"></div>
    <div class="marker angle-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Teja, please share the link of *Paulie_D previous solution* for reference. Regarding your question: as it seems you need a 3x3 grid (9 cells) with the circles in the center. You can use any kind of gridlike CSS element for that, **table, grid, flexbox**. Your circle goes in the center (cell 5). If you only have 6 texts, then you need 3 columns: col1 = 3 rows, col2 = 1 row and col3 = 3 rows (total of 7 cells). Can be easily solves with 'flexbox layout'.

Comment: @RenevanderLende It would be better if you post the working solution for better understanding. TIA

Comment: True, but I really would like you to have a try first as it will force you to learn about columns, tables, flexbox, grid and designing the logical structure of your page elements. Many people on SO can code the full page for you, but that's not how SO works, read [reprex]. Go the extra mile and we'll help you out...

Comment: Maybe my answer on [SO62815794](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824867/2015909) will give you some ideas. Run the snippet and scroll down to *demo 2, the patch grid* (**3x3 <div><div>** may be the code you need) and *sudoku, a patch grid demo* (a 3x3 grid of 3x3 grids). I think it will keep you quite busy for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is not entirely clear, but my guess is that you want to create some **info-graphic** about seeds with text around a nice graphic.

Instead of focusing on showing you how to create bordered circles with CSS and place text around them, I removed the text from your original image and cropped it. Because, as I suggested in my comment to visit my answer on [SO62815794](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824867/2015909), it made more sense to me to take that code and the cropped image and show you how to create a responsive **info-graphic** with *Flexbox Layout* and a *media query*.

**If this is not what you meant, please modify your answer and be more specific about what you need.** However, while it is fun to create a graphic with CSS, in terms of maintenance you would be much better off with a cropped image or SVG file (more graphical elements for creating custom shapes).

**The Snippet**

has two demos showing how to use *Flexbox Layout* combined with *Custom Attributes* to create responsively sizing **2D XxY** grids with the cropped image in the center.

- **demo 1** is a fairly straightforward 3x3 flexbox grid with equally sized cells
- **demo 2** is more complicated and has a main 3x1 grid with nested 1x2, 1x3 and 1x2 child grids giving it a more 'circular feel' than **demo 1**

The snippet is heavily commented and should be self explanatory, but additionally:

- I left your original `.outCircle` in the HTML, just disabled it.
- the cropped image is 138x138px PNG file (11.4Kb), with a transparent background (alpha channel) so you can play with the **info-graphic** `background-color` (`: White` for now)
- The `@media` considers anything smaller than 720px (W/H) to be a 'smartphone' and will **neither** show the image (or `.outCircle`) nor **any** grid layout.

All you need to do is some fine-tuning with spacing, colors and font-sizes.

**Make sure to go 'Full page' on SO and resize the browser window.**

```css
/*************************************/
/* main page structure, MOBILE first */
/*************************************/
body { height: 100vh; background-color: White }

.main-structure {
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;

    /* Center everything inside the element (vertical and horizontal) */
    justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center

    /* add your specific mobile settings */
}
.main-structure .outCircle { display: none } /* don't show on mobile */
.main-structure img        { display: none } /* ditto */

.main-structure ul { padding-right: 40px } /* [OPTIONAL] to make L/R padding equal */


/*************/
/* EYE-CANDY */
/*************/
[band*="header"] {
    background-color: rgba(254,190,0,1); /* egg yolk-ish */
    text-align: center
}

.main-structure .headline {
    width: 100%; /* stretch to fill parent */
    padding: .25em 1em; /* some inner spacing */
    
    color: CornflowerBlue;
    font-size: 1.25em; font-weight: bold;
}

.outCircle {
    position: relative; /* creates a new 'stacking context' for child elements */

    /* Center everything inside the element (vertical and horizontal) */
    justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width : 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;

    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.marker {
    position: absolute; /* direct positioning inside parent 'stacking context' */
    width: 3rem; height: 0.125rem;

    /* center element in parent */
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    background: linear-gradient(to right, black, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%);
}
.vert {
  width: 0.125rem; height: 3rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%);
}
.angle-1 { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg)  }
.angle-2 { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg) }


/*****************************/
/* DESKTOP specific settings */
/*****************************/

@media (min-width: 720px) and (min-height: 720px) { /* anything larger than average mobile */

    /* base flexbox patch grid structure */
    [patch],[patch]>* { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap } /* patch and cell containers */

    [patch]   { align-content: flex-start; position: relative }
    [patch]>* { flex-grow: 1;     /* [MANDATORY] */
                overflow: hidden; /* [OPTIONAL]  */
                /* Center everything inside the element (vertical and horizontal) */
                justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center }

    /* the "nine-patch", inspired by Android 9-patch image; essentially a 3x3 matrix */
    [patch^= "3x"]>*  { height    : 33.33333%; max-height: 33.33333% } /* ^...starts with */
    [patch*= "x3"]>*  { flex-basis: 33.33333%; max-width : 33.33333% } /* *...contains    */

    [patch^= "1x"]>*  { height: 100%; max-height: 100% } [patch*= "x1"]>* { flex-basis: 100%; max-width: 100% }
    [patch^= "2x"]>*  { height:  50%; max-height:  50% } [patch*= "x2"]>* { flex-basis:  50%; max-width:  50% }
    /* add your own specific patch cell sizes like below */
    /* 
        7x1 days in a week, 18x8 Periodic Table, 24x1 hours in a day, 22x6 keyboard+numpad, etc.
        just divide 100% by the required XxY values

        Usage:

        <parent-tag patch="XxY">
            requires X * Y number of child-tags to work properly
            <child-tag 1>
                ....
            <child-tag N>
        </parent-tag>
    */

    body { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) } /* light grey */

    .main-structure {
        flex-flow: row wrap; /* we have 3 rows of several columns */
        height: 75vmin; width: 75vmin; /* Modify to your needs */
        background-color: White;
    }

    [band*="info2"] .main-structure>[patch="1x2"] {
        max-width: 75%;
        /* instead of 100%, this will move the cells closer for a 'circular feel' */
    }
    .main-structure img { display: block; width: 80% } /* Modify to your needs */

    .main-structure .outCircle {
        /* flex for easy centering of '.inner' */
        display: flex; /* make visible */
    }
}

/**************************/
/* preferred global rules */
/**************************/
html,body            { width: 100%; max-width: 100% }

html                 { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box }
*, *:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: inherit; box-sizing: inherit }

body                 { margin: 0 } /* remove default <body> spacing */
/*
    Above CSS defines ALL elements to use 'border-box' (most common practice nowadays)

    make sure to own the boxmodel knowledge!

    MDN 'The box model': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model 
    w3schools 'CSS box-sizing Property': https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp
*/
/*

    All math reference: https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html

*/
/* responsive base font size using y = mx + b */
html   { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.625rem) } /* (320,12)(1280,18) */

/* Simple banding attribute for use in 'Landing Page' layout */
[band] { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; align-content: center }

body[padded="1"],
body[padded="0"] [band*="padded"] {
/*
    responsive page padding
    and responsive band padding (same as responsive page padding, but at band level)

    Top/Bottom padding: p1(320,16) p2(1920, 72) => 0.035x + 4.8  => vary from 16 to  72px
    Left/Right padding: p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 => vary from  8 to 320px

    'Band padding' is only active when 'page padding' is off (0)
*/
    padding: calc(3.5vh + 4.8px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}
/* for debugging (put in <body>) */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dotted }
```

```html
<body outlines="0" padded="0">

<div band="padded.header">
    <h1>3x3 easy grid with two dummies</h1>
    <h3>easy, but straight columns</h3>
</div>

<div band="padded.info1">
    <div class="main-structure" patch="3x3">
        <div>
            <div class="headline">Meet the farmer</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="headline dummy"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="headline">Provenance</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="headline">Certification</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zvBCdxp4/circles.png">
        </div>
        <!--div class="outCircle">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="marker horiz"></div>
                <div class="marker vert"></div>
                <div class="marker angle-1"></div>
                <div class="marker angle-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div -->
        <div>
            <div class="headline">Life of the seed</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="headline">History of seed</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="headline dummy"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="headline">IoT data this seed season</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div band="padded.header">
    <h1>3x1 nested grid with 1x2, 1x3 and 1x2 child grids</h1>
    <h3>more complicated, but has rows with a 'circular feel'</h3>
</div>

<div band="padded.info2">
    <div class="main-structure" patch="3x1">
        <div patch="1x2">
            <div>
                <div class="headline">Meet the farmer</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="headline">Provenance</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div patch="1x3">
            <div>
                <div class="headline">Certification</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zvBCdxp4/circles.png">
            </div>
            <!--div class="outCircle">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="marker horiz"></div>
                    <div class="marker vert"></div>
                    <div class="marker angle-1"></div>
                    <div class="marker angle-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div -->
            <div>
                <div class="headline">Life of the seed</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div patch="1x2">
            <div>
                <div class="headline">History of seed</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="headline">IoT data this seed season</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap it in a div and give the `<div>` the following styling:

```
#circle {
    border: solid black 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10em; //Depends on the circles size..
    height: 10em;
}
```

Comment: I want the text for each line as show above in the image

Comment: This is what you said: *How to make lines around the circle which holds text around it*. Please adjust your question if you get the wrong answer. JaKa did post a good suggestion.

Comment: Corrected it. Even I do have uploaded the output image for reference

Comment: JaKa, modify `#circle` to `.inner` and remove the `width/height` settings and your solution works out of the box. It's not what the OP wants, but it does make your code runnable...

Comment: @Teja Maybe this is what you're looking for then: http://hansmuller-webkit.blogspot.com/2013/02/padding-rounded-rectangle.html