# Am I making some type conversion mistake here

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright so whats going on is I'm making a tic tac toe game, I know what an original idea ... I wanted to make this grid system to use in the game so that I could change the grid size to say 5x7 if i wanted but right now I'm stuck on the function thats supposed check if someone wins, I confidently believe all the data I'm passing in is correct data but have absolutely no idea why it isn't working.

here's a small piece and I'll link a file for the whole project at the very bottom
and if anyone has a better way they think this can be done please share it with me, I know this is super hard coded and it bothers me as well

```
        winCheck: (grid) => {
            Object.entries(grid).map(z => {
                let currentPos, cpul, cpu, cpur, cpl, cpr, cpbl, cpb, cpbr;
                //cpul = currentPos Up Left, cpbl = currentPos bottom Left etc this isnt a normal x,y grid - please check the html code to see how its structured
                currentPos = z[0].split('-');

                cpul = `${currentPos[0]-1}-${currentPos[1]-1}`;
                cpu = `${currentPos[0]-1}-${currentPos[1]}`; 
                cpur = `${currentPos[0]-1}-${currentPos[1]+1}`; 
                cpl = `${currentPos[0]}-${currentPos[1]-1}`; 
                cpr = `${currentPos[0]}-${currentPos[1]+1}`; 
                cpbl = `${currentPos[0]+1}-${currentPos[1]-1}`; 
                cpb = `${currentPos[0]+1}-${currentPos[1]}`; 
                cpbr = `${currentPos[0]+1}-${currentPos[1]+1}`; 
                console.log(z[1])
                if(z[1] == Data.activePlayer && grid[cpul] == Data.activePlayer && grid[cpbr] == Data.activePlayer) {
                    console.log('win')
                } else if(z[1] == Data.activePlayer && grid[cpu] == Data.activePlayer && grid[cpb] == Data.activePlayer) {
                    console.log('win')
                } else if(z[1] ==  Data.activePlayer && grid[cpur] == Data.activePlayer && grid[cpbl] == Data.activePlayer) {
                    console.log('win')
                } else if(z[1] ==  Data.activePlayer && grid[cpl] == Data.activePlayer && grid[cpr] == Data.activePlayer) {
                    console.log('win')
                } else {
                    console.log('lose')
                    console.log()
                }



                }
            )
        },
```

Right now I'm working with a 3x3 grid and activePlayer doesn't change yet - it's always x, even when every grid box has x in it, it still console logs lose and man is it driving me crazy

would very much appreciate it if someone could help out ty

Full file:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/740319964845572137/743360843185389700/tictactoe.zip

Comment: can you provide the grid parameter please?

Comment: @yagizhan.avci Data.mapObj will be passed in which is an object that looks like
{
"1-1": "inactive",
"1-2": "inactive",
"1-3": "inactive",
"2-1": "inactive",
"2-2": "inactive",
"2-3": "inactive",
"3-1": "inactive",
"3-2": "inactive",
"3-3": "inactive"
}

Comment: If you want to add/subtract like `${currentPos[0]-1}-${currentPos[1]-1}` you need to convert `currentPos[x]` to number or float first. Now the elements are treated as strings...

Comment: @RenevanderLende tysm, I got it all fixed up and we're running pretty well

Comment: Yeah, I made that same mistake a few times myself. Sometimes Javascript is too forgiving. Glad to be of help!

Comment: Ooh, I've got a nice CSS trick to create odd shaped matrixes (anything apart from 3x3, flexbox). Ask a new SO question on that when required and **comment here** to let me know you did (otherwise I will loose track). Works for all kinds of stuff: Sudoku, keyboard layout, periodic table, day/week/month view, all with the same base CSS (very few rules, 5 maybe 10). (Check my answer on [SO62815794](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824867/2015909), which uses this code: **the patch-grid**.)

Comment: @RenevanderLende I know its been a long time, really sorry - I have an idea in mind and yeah it requires a, well, sheared grid. Do you have a telegram or discord I could add you on and share the idea with you and we could discuss what the best way to do this would be?

Comment: @Ase Last, to email me: scroll down the 'About me' in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2015909/rene-van-der-lende?tab=profile). Make sure to put **SO63389746** in the subject.