# Use feather icons in CSS before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, svg, feathericons

I'm using feather icons in my project and I need to use a symbol of the feather icons sprite in a before pseudo-element. What I tried was to use the icon as a `background-image` in the CSS. I read online that Views tags in SVG files can be accessed by using `url("path/to/file.svg#viewname")`. Is it possible to use a similar way but to access a symbol in an SVG file?

What I tried :

```css
p::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url("feather-sprite.svg#search");
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

A sample of the feather icons sprite :

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="activity" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <polyline points="22 12 18 12 15 21 9 3 6 12 2 12"></polyline>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="airplay" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M5 17H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h16a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-1"></path>
            <polygon points="12 15 17 21 7 21 12 15"></polygon>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="alert-circle" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
            <line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"></line>
            <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12.01" y2="16"></line>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="alert-octagon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <polygon points="7.86 2 16.14 2 22 7.86 22 16.14 16.14 22 7.86 22 2 16.14 2 7.86 7.86 2"></polygon>
            <line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"></line>
            <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12.01" y2="16"></line>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="alert-triangle" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M10.29 3.86L1.82 18a2 2 0 0 0 1.71 3h16.94a2 2 0 0 0 1.71-3L13.71 3.86a2 2 0 0 0-3.42 0z"></path>
            <line x1="12" y1="9" x2="12" y2="13"></line>
            <line x1="12" y1="17" x2="12.01" y2="17"></line>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="align-center" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <line x1="18" y1="10" x2="6" y2="10"></line>
            <line x1="21" y1="6" x2="3" y2="6"></line>
            <line x1="21" y1="14" x2="3" y2="14"></line>
            <line x1="18" y1="18" x2="6" y2="18"></line>
        </symbol>
        ...
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't use symbols. Use nested svg elements or fragments or groups. Please read about [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Comment: Hi Ekko, welcome at SO! Early July I answered to [SO62815794: How do i make my burger menu into 9 dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824867/2015909) showing how to use in-document SVG with `<symbol>` and `<use>`. There's a lot going on in the demo, so run the snippet first (full page view), do some hovering and resizing and then check the code. This may be of use to you.... SVG stuff is in the last 2 `<div band="fullmenu.cols.padded">`. The SVG is at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: If you are into W3C standard Custom Elements API (aka Web Components) yet... I included 281 Feather icons in the 5000+ icons ``<svg-icon is="activity">`` Custom Element: https://iconmeister.github.io